# Helm JSON being converted to map in configmap

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have an array of json objects like this in my values.yaml:

```
key: [{A:a, 1:2}, {B:b, 3:4}, {C:c, 5:6}]
```

when it gets moved to my config map it becomes:

```
key: [map[A:a 1:2] map[B:b 3:4] map[C:c 5:6]]
```

I'm not doing anything fancy with the template:

```
data:
  {{- range $key, $val := .Values.configs }}
  {{ $key }}: {{ $val | quote }}
  {{- end }}
```

So, how can I prevent helm from making that conversion with my JSON array?

Comment: What is values.config? Is that what you shared as key?

Comment: yes. in my Values.yaml I have a section called configs, and I'm running a loop over that section to grab all of the configs. This loop works fine, it just stumbles whenever there is a value that needs to be a json

Comment: Have you tried to quote the value in your values file so it is interpreted as a string and not nested yaml/json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the form you have now, the value of `key` is an array of objects, and you're then getting the default Go serialization.

If you instead want it to pass through exactly as that specific JSON string, you can quote it in your Helm values:

```yaml
key: '[{A:a, 1:2}, {B:b, 3:4}, {C:c, 5:6}]'
#    ^  surround the string with quotes   ^
```

Or, if you want to keep the values with that syntax (or a more complex YAML structure), Helm includes a [`toJson` template function](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions) that can write out the structure as a JSON string:

```
{{ $key }}: {{ $val | toJson | quote }}
{{/*                  ^^^^^^       */}}
```